# Why does Dapper throw an OracleException when i run a query or command with parameters?

Tags: oracle, exception, orm, oracle11g, dapper

I am evaluation dapper but i already running into some problems.

I am trying to do this

```
using (IDbConnection connection = GetConnection())
{
    connection.Open();
    var result = connection.Query(
        "select * from myTable where ID_PK = @a;", new { a = 1 });
}
```

It throws an ORA-00936: missing expression OracleException at line 393 in the SqlMapper.cs

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

When i remove the parameter i get the whole table into the result variable.

The query works without problems in sqldeveloper. I am using the Oracle.DataAccess Assembly 2.112.2.0

Comment: I think oracle has a different schema for named parameter, did you try :a instead of @a ?

Comment: This is the schema for named parameters in dapper. Dapper should take care of different rdbms schemas

Comment: Ok I thought Dapper just uses Ado.Net and since the query is a string, the format of the parameters is relevant. Since I do not seem to have enough knowledge, just a last tip:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212992/using-dapper-with-oracle
mentions problems with the oracle parameters (which sould be fixed now) - maybe you can check it. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, I am stupid. Bernhard, you are absolutly right, it has to be :a Please enter your first comment as the accepted answer. m(

Comment: An upvote on my comment would have been nice, since it seemed to help...

Comment: @Bernard just post your comment as answer so we can close the loop here.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I think oracle has a different schema for named parameter, did you try `:a` instead of `@a`?

Comment: For me, this is not an acceptable answer.  I need Dapper/Dapper.Contrib to work universally with Sql Server and Oracle.  Contrib is the worst offender here, as I don't control the bind parameter in the statement.  The @/: character should be managed by Dapper.  It's a good answer when supporting Oracle only, and for that I up voted the post.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it works with ":" if we trying to insert records in oracle database table.

Just try like this:

```
var count = connection.Execute(@"INSERT INTO COMPANY_USER(UserId , UserName) values (:UserId, :UserName)", new[] { new { UserId = 1, UserName = "Sam" }, new { UserId = 2, UserName = "Don" }, new { UserId = 3, UserName = "Mike" } });
```

Answer (score 3):

It also works with IN list:

var partialList = new List();

var list = await db.QueryAsync("select bla1, blah2 
FROM tablename 
WHERE stringcolumn1 IN :ListofValues", new { ListofValues = partialList });