# execute sql update from visual c#

Tags: c#, sql

i have my project, access oracle database from my visual c#
i have trouble using update command

here my code

```
string updatetodb = "update tugas_oop ";
updatetodb += "set stok = :i_stok, ";
updatetodb += "dana_keluar = :i_dana_keluar ";
updatetodb += "where nama_barang = '" + nama_barang[i] + "' and satuan = '" + satuan[i] + "';";

cmd.CommandText = updatetodb;

OracleParameter istok = new OracleParameter();
istok.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
istok.Value = updatestok;
istok.ParameterName = "i_stok";

OracleParameter idana_keluar = new OracleParameter();
idana_keluar.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
idana_keluar.Value = updatedanakeluar;
idana_keluar.ParameterName = "i_dana_keluar";

cmd.Parameters.Add(istok);
cmd.Parameters.Add(idana_keluar);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and i got error message ora-00911
can you tell me, where i made mistake?

Comment: Why are you only partially using parameters? `nama_barang[i]` and `satuan[i]` should also be parameterised.

Comment: have u heard of stored Procedures ? read on those

Comment: What are the values of upatestok and updatedanakeluar? Is this your exact code? Unless you explicitly set the `BindByName` property of the commnand to true the names of the parameters are irrelevant, and they are bound by position. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3876856/1048425) for more details on this

Answer (score 0):

Replace with

```
istok.ParameterName = ":i_stok";

idana_keluar.ParameterName = ":i_dana_keluar";
```

i suggest you to use `string.Format` (Ensure that you don't have problem about quote)

```
string.Format("update tugas_oop set stok = :i_stok, dana_keluar = :i_dana_keluar where nama_barang = {0} and satuan = {1}",nama_barang[i],satuan[i]);
```

Note : For me i prefer use stored procedure in order to validate your query before calling

Comment: Why would you suggest using `string.Format` over additional parameters? Parameters not only prevent [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/), they also remove chances of conversion errors, or data truncation, and separate code from data for easier readability.

Comment: I mean why would you not suggest using parameters for nama_barang as well as i_stok and i_dana_keluar. i.e make the SQLCommand `update tugas_oop set stok = :i_stok, dana_keluar = :i_dana_keluar where nama_barang = :i_nama_barang and satuan = :i_satuan`, then add parameters to the command using `command.Parameters.Add("i_nama_barang", nama_barang[i]);`

Comment: Ok ok i inderstand your remark GarethD, thank's for precision