# Update statement working in SQL Developer but not in C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, sql-update, odp.net

I have a small update query which works in SQL Developer.

```
UPDATE people
SET months = 8
WHERE number = 599
```

Fairly straight forward. And it works - this also works in C#.
The problem is the moment I want to use Parameters (which works on number but not on months) it will stop working.

I have this code in C#:

```
 using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            OracleCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE people " +
                              "SET months = :months " +
                              "WHERE number = :number";
            command.Parameters.Add(":number", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = number;
            command.Parameters.Add(":months", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = months;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

They are both of type Number in oracle, and I've tried changing the OracleDbType to Decimal, and pretty much everything without success.
The odd thing is, that the :number parameters works, but months doesn't get updated (it won't crash, it just doesn't update).
However if i change the :months parameter, to a static value like 7 - it will work.

Comment: Did you watch CommandText during the debug? What is the value of the months?

Comment: "UPDATE people SET months = :months WHERE number = :number"
That's what the CommandText is. Looks alright i guess?
If i were to changed months to a 7 - it'll work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, i found out why this wasn't working, it wasn't because of the colons (you can add colons in parameters without it being a problem):

```
command.Parameters.Add(":months", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = months;
```

The problem was that i was adding the parameters in a different order than I was using them.

So if in your SQL statement you are adding parameters in a specific order, you should follow that order when you add your OracleCommand.Parameters, like so:

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        OracleCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "UPDATE people " +
                          "SET months = :months " +
                          "WHERE number = :number";
        command.Parameters.Add(":months", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = months;
        command.Parameters.Add(":number", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = number;

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: You can avoid this by setting command.BindByName = true; See: [C# parameterized queries for Oracle - serious & dangerous bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876856/c-sharp-parameterized-queries-for-oracle-serious-dangerous-bug)

Comment: If I could upvote this more than once I'd do it a hundred times.  Fighting this for hours.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You should add parameters without leading ':' (look [here](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/parameters.html)), try this:

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    OracleCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE people" +
                      "SET months = :months " +
                      "WHERE number = :number";
    command.Parameters.Add("number", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = number;
    command.Parameters.Add("months", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = months;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Also you are missing space after `:months` in query.

Comment: I found the problem, though this was not the solution. I'll post my own answer. Thanks though.
The space was just a typo on stackoverflow, had spaces in my code.

Comment: @balls: In the future, consider posting code that actually resembles the one you are using. Otherwise people are unable to help you.

Comment: This was exactly how my code is, with the one difference of the spaces. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

your command text should be

```
 command.CommandText = "UPDATE people SET months = :months WHERE number = :number";
```

Note the spaces i have added