# How to add records to an Oracle table with foreign keys?

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle

I'm trying to do CRUD operations in my Oracle DB through C# WPF.

I created a DataGrid displaying all the rows in my table, which I was able to connect to my DB. However, when I try to input values in the form on the left side, I get this error: System.InvalidOperationException: オブジェクトの現在の状態に問題があるため、操作は有効ではありません。

Project Code (プロジェクト) and Task Code (分類) belong to a different table and are referenced in my main table.

```
// Sample of how I fill the Project Code combobox
private void fillProjectComboBox()
        {
            string sql = "SELECT PROJECT_CODE, PROJECT_NAME FROM TASK_PROJECT";
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            try
            {
                cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string project = dr.GetString(0);
                    regProjectBox.Items.Add(project);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

private void RegisterNewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO TASK_INFO(USER_ID, ATTENDED_DATE, START_TIME, END_TIME, TASK_HOURS, PROJECT_CODE, TASK_CODE, TASK_DESCRIPTION)" +
        " VALUES(:USER_ID, :ATTENDED_DATE, :START_TIME, :END_TIME, :TASK_HOURS, :PROJECT_CODE, :TASK_CODE, :TASK_DESCRIPTION)";
    cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("USER_ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20).Value = "test";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("ATTENDED_DATE", OracleDbType.NChar, 10).Value = regDateTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("START_TIME", OracleDbType.NChar, 5).Value = regStartTimeTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("END_TIME", OracleDbType.NChar, 5).Value = regEndTimeTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("TASK_HOURS", OracleDbType.Int16, 3).Value = int.TryParse(regTaskTimeTextBox.Text, out int result);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("TASK_DESCRIPTION", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50).Value = regTaskDescTextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("PROJECT_CODE", OracleDbType.NChar, 9).Value = regProjectBox.SelectedValue;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("TASK_CODE", OracleDbType.NChar, 9).Value = regTaskBox.SelectedValue;

    try
    {
        int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (n > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Done!");
            this.viewDataGrid();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Is there something I should know about adding records into tables with foreign keys? In a different window, I was able to add new records into my Project Code and Task Code tables, so this is only a problem with my main table.

Edited to include error:

```
Exception thrown: 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' in Oracle.DataAccess.dll
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TIMESUSER.SYS_C007051) violated - parent key not found
   Location Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable, OracleLogicalTransaction m_OracleLogicalTransaction)
   Location Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck, OracleLogicalTransaction m_OracleLogicalTransaction)
   Location  Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   Location Times.ViewListWindow.RegisterNewButton_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 場所 C:\Users\neicy\source\repos\Times\Times\ViewListWindow.xaml.cs:Line 231
```

Apparently, it was mainly a matter of ordering the cmd.Parameters.Add according to how you insert them in your query. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876856/c-sharp-parameterized-queries-for-oracle-serious-dangerous-bug) for more info
**CORRECTED VERSION:**

```
private void fillProjectComboBox()
        {
            DataTable dtProject = new DataTable();
            string sql = "SELECT ID, PROJECT_CODE FROM TASK_PROJECT ORDER BY PROJECT_CODE";
            var cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
            using (OracleDataAdapter oracleDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                oracleDataAdapter.Fill(dtProject);
            }
            regProjectBox.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
            regProjectBox.DisplayMemberPath = "PROJECT_CODE";
            regProjectBox.ItemsSource = dtProject.DefaultView;
        }

private void RegisterNewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO TASK_INFO(TASK_INFO_ID, USER_ID, ATTENDED_DATE, START_TIME, END_TIME, TASK_HOURS, PROJECT_ID, TASK_ID, TASK_DESCRIPTION)" +
                " VALUES(SEQ_TASK_INFO.NEXTVAL, :USER_ID, :ATTENDED_DATE, :START_TIME, :END_TIME, :TASK_HOURS, :PROJECT_ID, :TASK_ID, :TASK_DESCRIPTION)";
            var cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("USER_ID", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = 1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("ATTENDED_DATE", OracleDbType.NChar, 10).Value = regDateTextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("START_TIME", OracleDbType.NChar, 5).Value = regStartTimeTextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("END_TIME", OracleDbType.NChar, 5).Value = regEndTimeTextBox.Text;
            int taskHours;
            if (int.TryParse(regTaskTimeTextBox.Text, out taskHours))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("TASK_HOURS", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = taskHours;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("TASK_HOURS", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = 0;
            }
            cmd.Parameters.Add("PROJECT_ID", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = 1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("TASK_ID", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = 1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("TASK_DESCRIPTION", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50).Value = regTaskDescTextBox.Text;

            try
            {
                int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (n > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Done!");
                    this.viewDataGrid();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Source);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            //this.AUD(sql, 0);
            registerNewButton.IsEnabled = false;
            registerUpdateButton.IsEnabled = true;
            registerDeleteButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Could you please translate `System.InvalidOperationException: オブジェクトの現在の状態に問題があるため、操作は有効ではありません。`? A Stacktrace or a row would also be welcome..

Comment: there is missing space before `VALUES` in your insert statement

Comment: You should not parse an `Int` without errorhandling directly from a `TextBox`: `Int16.Parse(regTaskTimeTextBox.Text);` Use `TryParse` instead.

Comment: I added the space and tried using TryParse but it still doesn't work. Edited the post

Comment: I changed `cmd = new OracleCommand(sql)` to `cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn)` and I got a different error. I would appreciate it if you could check

Comment: @Neicy Please read the text of the error message, there is exactly what is wrong. You insert a record in a table with a foreign key. with this key there is no record in the parent table

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to C#. The `regProjectBox.SelectedValue` refers to a table of pre-existing project codes. The relationship exists in my DB, I just don't know how to (or if I have to) make the relationship in C#. I would appreciate a point in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check which table the `TIMESUSER.SYS_C007051` constraint refers to.
As you have a field named `USER_ID` and the constraint is TIMES**USER**.SYS_C007051, the problem could be that you don't have a user named `test`
Or maybe I am totally wrong because I don't remember if `TIMESUSER` here is a schema name or a table name. Without knowing which relationship is on error it's hard to guess.
**EDIT**
I can't guess the true origin of the error but I am quite sure it's due to the NCHAR type usage. I don't think it's a good practice to use this datatype as PK/FK furthermore if the data content does not exactly match the field type.
Here how I would do things to avoid this issue (and many others that you might meet later) :
1. In the database, add some ID fields (numeric) to use as PK/FK and some sequences to increase their value (not needed if >= Oracle12c as there is an auto-increment datatype) :

```sql
-- Projects
CREATE TABLE TASK_PROJECT (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    PROJECT_CODE NCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    PROJECT_NAME NVARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT PK_TASK_PROJECT PRIMARY KEY (ID) CLUSTERED
);
-- Unique index to keep sure that PROJECT_CODE remains unique in the table
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_TASK_PROJECT_CODE  ON TASK_PROJECT(PROJECT_CODE);
-- Sequence to use to increment TASK_PROJECT.ID
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TASK_PROJECT (
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
);

-- Tasks
CREATE TABLE TASK_TASK (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    TASK_CODE NCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    TASK_NAME NVARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT PK_TASK_TASK PRIMARY KEY (ID) CLUSTERED
);
-- Unique index to keep sure that TASK_CODE remains unique in the table
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_TASK_TASK_CODE  ON TASK_TASK(TASK_CODE);
-- Sequence to use to increment TASK_TASK.ID
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TASK_TASK (
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
);

-- Users
CREATE TABLE TASK_USER (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    USER_LOGIN VARCHAR2(50),
    CONSTRAINT PK_TASK_USER PRIMARY KEY (ID) CLUSTERED
);
-- Unique index to keep sure that USER_LOGIN remains unique in the table
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_TASK_USER_LOGIN ON TASK_USER(USER_LOGIN);
-- Sequence to use to increment TASK_USER.ID
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TASK_USER (
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
);

-- Task info
CREATE TABLE TASK_INFO (
    TASK_INFO_ID INT NOT NULL,
    USER_ID INT NOT NULL,
    PROJECT_ID INT NOT NULL,
    TASK_ID INT NOT NULL,
    ATTENDED_DATE NCHAR(10),
    START_TIME NCHAR(5),
    END_TIME NCHAR(5),
    TASK_HOURS INT,
    TASK_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(50),
    CONSTRAINT PK_TASK_INFO PRIMARY KEY (TASK_INFO_ID) CLUSTERED,
    CONSTRAINT FK_TASK_INFO_TASK_PROJECT FOREIGN KEY (PROJECT_ID) REFERENCES TASK_PROJECT(ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TASK_INFO_TASK_TASK FOREIGN KEY (TASK_ID) REFERENCES TASK_TASK(ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TASK_INFO_TASK_USER FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES TASK_USER(ID)
);
-- Sequence to use to increment TASK_INFO.ID
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TASK_INFO (
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
);
```

2. On C# application side :

```
        // Sample of how I fill the Project Code combobox
        private void fillProjectComboBox()
        {
            DataTable dtProject = new DataTable();

            // For the moment, you don't seem to use the field PROJECT_NAME, so no need to retrieve it
            //string sql = "SELECT PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_CODE, PROJECT_NAME FROM TASK_PROJECT";
            // I added an ORDER BY PROJECT_CODE to ensure the order in the combo box
            string sql = "SELECT PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_CODE FROM TASK_PROJECT ORDER BY PROJECT_CODE";
            var cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
            using (OracleDataAdapter oracleDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                oracleDataAdapter.Fill(dtProject);
            }
            regProjectBox.SelectedValuePath = "PROJECT_ID";
            regProjectBox.DisplayMemberPath = "PROJECT_CODE";
            regProjectBox.ItemsSource = dtProject.DefaultView;
        }

        private void RegisterNewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Here we use TASK_ID and PROJECT_ID instead of TASK_CODE and PROJECT_CODE
            string sql = "INSERT INTO TASK_INFO(TASK_INFO_ID, USER_ID, ATTENDED_DATE, START_TIME, END_TIME, TASK_HOURS, PROJECT_ID, TASK_ID, TASK_DESCRIPTION)" +
                " VALUES(SEQ_TASK_INFO.NEXTVAL, :USER_ID, :ATTENDED_DATE, :START_TIME, :END_TIME, :TASK_HOURS, :PROJECT_ID, :TASK_ID, :TASK_DESCRIPTION)";
            var cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
            // Here I changed the defintion of USER_ID from login to a numeric identifier  of this login
            cmd.Parameters.Add("USER_ID", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = 1; // Identifier related to the user "test"
            cmd.Parameters.Add("ATTENDED_DATE", OracleDbType.NChar, 10).Value = regDateTextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("START_TIME", OracleDbType.NChar, 5).Value = regStartTimeTextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("END_TIME", OracleDbType.NChar, 5).Value = regEndTimeTextBox.Text;
            // WRONG !!!- TryParse returns a boolean that indicates if the parsing was successful or not
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("TASK_HOURS", OracleDbType.Int16, 3).Value = int.TryParse(regTaskTimeTextBox.Text, out int result);
            int taskHours;
            if (int.TryParse(regTaskTimeTextBox.Text, out taskHours))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("TASK_HOURS", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = taskHours;
            } else {
                // Handle task hours if no numeric value
                cmd.Parameters.Add("TASK_HOURS", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = 0;
            }
            cmd.Parameters.Add("TASK_DESCRIPTION", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50).Value = regTaskDescTextBox.Text;
            // Change Project code to project id
            // Explict cast as int to be sure you assign a numeric value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("PROJECT_ID", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = (int)regProjectBox.SelectedValue;
            // Change Task code to task id
            // Explict cast as int to be sure you assign a numeric value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("TASK_ID", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = (int)regTaskBox.SelectedValue;
        }
```

Comment: I checked my database and the constraint is a FK constraint referring to my TASK_PROJECT table

Comment: PROJECT_CODE is defined as NChar and not NVarchar. So maybe some issues with the trailing whitespaces ? Try to create and use a project code ```000000000``` to check if the problem remains with this value

Comment: Btw, did you check the content of ```regProjectBox.SelectedValue``` ? As you use it, there are great chances it is ```null``` because you have not set the ```ValueMember``` attribute. Have a look at ```regProjectBox.SelectedItem``` instead

Comment: I tried hardcoding the value into `cmd.Parameters.Add("TASK_CODE", OracleDbType.NChar, 9).Value = "TC0001";` Where TC0001 is an existing TASK_CODE in its table, but it's still giving the same error. When I tried printing the values, both `regProjectBox.SelectedValue` and `regProjectBox.SelectedValue` return the same value (TP0001) with different number of trailing zeros. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Try to hardcode the insert with "TP0001   " for project and "TC0001   " for task. It is not about trailing 0 but trailing spaces. Your string length must be 9. Because when you have created the project with "TP0001", Oracle must have stored it as "TP0001   "

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant trailing spaces. Still gives the same error though :(

Comment: Hi Olivia! Thanks for your help. I tried editing my database, but I'm getting an `ORA-01722: invalid number` error. I've tried hardcoding the values into the columns of type int, but it's still the same

Comment: Have you also hardcoded the TASK_HOURS parameter : I saw the code I posted had a flaw if ```regTaskTimeTextBox``` was not a numeric value. I edited this part and also added explicit ```int``` casting when getting the SelectedValue to be sure of the assigned value data type

Comment: I did! I also did for project and task id, made sure there was at least one record in each of the tables in the database, but it's still giving me the invalid number error

Comment: Hi Olivia! I found out the problem. I had to put the parameters in the order of insertion, so I put `cmd.Parameters.Add("TASK_DESCRIPTION", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50).Value = regTaskDescTextBox.Text;` in last. Thank you soso much for your help! I've been pulling at my hair for two weeks now trying to make this work. I appreciate the tip on best practices, I'll be sure to model my DB better next time.